# How do I remove these tags with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, xhtml, replace

I'm still learning regex (obviously) and i can't figure it out, and i want to do it the right way rather than doing it the long way. How can I:

Find all `<p>` or `</p>` and replace with a `\n` except the first `<p>` and last `</p>` in which case replace with nothing, just remove, and for `<br>`, `<br />` and `<br/>` replace with `\n` also.

With Regex OR something else. I'm getting this from a jQuery $.get() return. So, please don't flame me about it, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: OK, so how do I do this then? It doesn't have to be regex.

Comment: Your question is rather underspecified. For example, what happens if there are other elements between the `<p>` elements? Or if there are block level elements containing some of the `<p>` elements? Can you limit the range of possible inputs? It might also help to take a step back and explain what you expect to achieve by replacing the tags with '\n'?

Comment: There wont be. It's a simple <textarea>. The \n is so that the client doesn't have to know HTML but retain the spacing. I'm personally doing this: '<p>'+str.replace(/\n\n/g,'</p><p>').replace(/\n/,'<br>')+'</p>' and right now im doing this to convert it back: str.replace(/<p>|<\/p>|<br>/g,"\n").replace(/\n$/,'');

Comment: Well, I think it is OK to use regex in this situation, but if I was doing it I'd just reverse the operation, so use a combination of regex and normal string processing. i.e. Handle the starting open p tag and the ending close p tag outside the regex, then replace the character sequence '</p><p>' with '\n\n' and the character sequence '<br>' with '\n'.

Comment: <p> is an incredibly wonderful construct in HTML because it does not require a matching </p> Oh what fun!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has rather nice tools for dealing with an xml (or xhtml) DOM.  Use [those](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp).

Comment: or y'know.. jquery or prototype or something.

Comment: OK, so im getting a massive string of text with <p>s and <br>s, how do I convert it with jQuery to remove all those?

Answer (score 0):

In Regex perspective, to make the first `<p>` become an exception, you must identify a pattern which makes the first `<p>` fails. For example, if text before first `<p>` is `abcxyz`, that is, `abcxyz<p>`, then you search every `<p>` which is not preceded by `abcxyz`, so that the first `<p>` doesn't match. Using regex, it becomes: `(?<!abcxyz)<p>`

To make the last `</p>` become an exception, you must identify a pattern which makes the last `</p>` fails. For example, if text after last `</p>` is `abcxyz`, that is, `</p>abcxyz`, then you search every `</p>` which is not followed by `abcxyz`, so that the last `</p>` doesn't match. Using regex, it becomes: `</p>(?!abcxyz)`

Although JavaScript support positive and negative *look-ahead*, unfortunately, JavaScript regex doesn't support neither positive nor negative *look-behind*. Indeed, there are some [dirty tricks to mimic look-behind in JavaScript](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript), however, not all look-behind construct can be mimicked.

Thus, if possible, try to identify a pattern which makes the first `<p>` fails, but use negative look-ahead.

To replace the first `<p>` and the last `</p>` with nothing, you can inverse the logic we use above, and you have to do this in separate step.

To replace `<br>`, `<br />`, `<br/>` with `\n`, search for: `<br\s*\/?>`, and replace with `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to allow the browser to do it for you. In IE and WebKit, you could assign your HTML as the innerHTML of a `<div>` and get its `innerText`. However, that won't work in Firefox or Opera. Here's a slightly bizarre use of the `Selection` object that will do it:

```
function getInnerText(html) {
    var text = "";
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = html;

    document.body.appendChild(div);
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(div);
        sel.addRange(range);
        text = sel.toString();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
    } else if (document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(div);
        text = range.text;
    }
    document.body.removeChild(div);
    return text.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").replace(/\r/g, "\n");
}
```